# View is not updated after the scope updates

Tags: angularjs

```
                             setTimeout(function () {
                                  $scope.$apply(function () {
                                      $scope.Images = data;
                                      //$scope.$apply();
                                   });
                               }, 2000);

                               setInterval(function () {
                                   $scope.Images = data;
                                   $scope.$apply()
                               }, 500);


                               $timeout(function () {
                                   $scope.Images = data;
                               }, 500);
                           })
```

I have tried all the option listed above in the controller but my view is not getting updated when i upload new image.

Here $scope.Images is Array and after the image is uploaded in the function i am getting all the images and assign all the images to $scope.Images, Updated data is coming , $scope.Images is also updated but related view is not refreshed.

Lines in the view :

```
   <div ng-repeat="Image in Images" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 gallery-item">

                <a href={{Image.standard}} class="gallery-link" data-gallery>
                    <img ng-src={{Image.standard}} class="img-rounded" width="100%" height="262.22px" ng-cloak>
                </a>
            </div>
```

Please help i am stuck :(

Comment: Can you make a plunker / fiddle / code snippet reproducing your issue ? Are you sure the Images array is being filled correctly ? can you show the code getting the data ?

Comment: Can you try adding double quotes around `{{}}`, like `ng-src="{{Image.standard}}"`? After that can you also try moving the image out to the same level with `<a>` for testing purpose?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

consider passing the $scope variable to the code which is run at a later date, outside of angular; example:

```
setInterval(
   (function ($scope) { 
       return function(){
           $scope.Images = data;
           $scope.$apply()
       }
   })($scope), 500);
```

This creates a function with a parameter $scope, which allows injection of the $scope variable at any time.

I know it looks weird at first, but this construction has proven useful in such situations.